# What to do with questions supplying images instead of code snippet

Tags: discussion

I see a lot questions nowadays featuring image links when with a simple copy-paste would be enough to get the code snippet as text.

Is there a sanction for this kind of use?

Note: I am cool with the images when they are the only way to display the problem. But stack traces and code snippets should only be in text.

Comment: Since there is no code, I would flag as "unclear what you are asking". Images should be supplementary, not the sole or main description of the problem.

Comment: Downvote such questions, and flag them as "lacking an MCVE". If you're feeling kind, you could comment and tell the OP to add the actual code in text form. If they refuse to improve their question, there's no point in helping them. (Also a reason *not* to edit in the text yourself - save your editing for those who deserve it.)